# Error when using std::from_chars with g++-10.2.1

Tags: g++, c++20

So, unfortunately, I cannot reproduce the error, since it seems to be fixed in newer g++ versions, but I cannot compile the following [code](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=0181b78e64198717):

```
#include <charconv>
#include <concepts>
#include <optional>
#include <string_view>

template<std::floating_point T>
std::optional<T> to_float(std::string_view s)
{
    T value;
    if (std::from_chars(s.data(), s.data() + s.size(), value).ec == std::errc{})
        return value;
    return {};
}
  
int main()
{
    to_float<float>("0");
    return 0;
}
```

It yields the following error:

> In instantiation of ‘std::optional<_Tp> to_float(std::string_view)
> [with T = float; std::string_view = std::basic_string_view]’:
> main.cpp:633:92:   required from here main.cpp:36:24: error: no
> matching function for call to
> ‘from_chars(std::basic_string_view::const_pointer,
> std::basic_string_view::const_pointer, float&)’    36 |     if
> (std::from_chars(s.data(), s.data() + s.size(), value).ec ==
> std::errc{})
> |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ In file included from main.cpp:25: /usr/include/c++/10/charconv:595:5:
> note: candidate: ‘template
> std::__detail::__integer_from_chars_result_type<_Tp>
> std::from_chars(const char*, const char*, _Tp&, int)’   595 |
> from_chars(const char* __first, const char* __last, _Tp& __value,
> |     ^~~~~~~~~~ /usr/include/c++/10/charconv:595:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed: In file included from
> /usr/include/c++/10/bits/move.h:57,
> from /usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_pair.h:59,
> from /usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
> from /usr/include/c++/10/vector:60: /usr/include/c++/10/type_traits: In substitution of ‘template<bool
> _Cond, class _Tp> using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if::type [with bool _Cond = false; _Tp = std::from_chars_result]’:
> /usr/include/c++/10/charconv:584:11:   required by substitution of
> ‘template using __integer_from_chars_result_type =
> std::enable_if_t<std::_*or*<std::_*or*<std::is_same<typename
> std::remove_cv<  >::type, signed char>,
> std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<
>
> > ::type, short int>, std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<  >::type, int>, std::is_same<typename
> > std::remove_cv<  >::type, long int>,
> > std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv< 
> > ::type, long long int> >, std::_*or*<std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<  >::type, unsigned char>,
> > std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv< 
> > ::type, short unsigned int>, std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<  >::type, unsigned int>, std::is_same<typename
> > std::remove_cv<  >::type, long unsigned int>,
> > std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv< 
> > ::type, long long unsigned int> >, std::is_same<char, typename std::remove_cv<  >::type> >::value,
> > std::from_chars_result> [with _Tp = float]’
> > /usr/include/c++/10/charconv:595:5:   required by substitution of
> > ‘template
> > std::__detail::__integer_from_chars_result_type<_Tp>
> > std::from_chars(const char*, const char*, _Tp&, int) [with _Tp =
> > float]’ main.cpp:36:24:   required from ‘std::optional<_Tp>
> > to_float(std::string_view) [with T = float; std::string_view =
> > std::basic_string_view]’ main.cpp:633:92:   required from here
> > /usr/include/c++/10/type_traits:2554:11: error: no type named ‘type’
> > in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, std::from_chars_result>’  2554 |
> > using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<_Cond, _Tp>::type;

I'm using `g++ version` is `g++ (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110`. Any ideas how I can solve this issue? Using a newer g++ version is not possible, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The floating point overloads of `std::from_chars` are implemented in libstdc++ only starting with version 11.

See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html. Look for "P0067R5".

So the functionality you try to use is simply not present in that GCC version.